# Sometimes Query Data is Incomplete - Pulling Results into Excel with VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have a query setup in an Access DB ('10). My users enter parameters into an Excel tool ('10), which uses VBA to pull the results of the query into the Excel tool.

**Problem:** Sometimes (1/50 times I'd guess) it will pull incomplete data, and I don't understand why.

It's the inconsistency that confuses me. My best guess is that *something* is causing the final piece of the code to activate and close the connection early. But I'm unsure why it would occassionally do so.

**The Code:**
*I updated the code slightly to include some error catching. The issue has persisted.*

```
Sub ParameterQuery_Awesome()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

On Error GoTo Whoa

'Step 1: Declare your variables
Dim MyDatabase As DAO.Database
Dim MyQueryDef As DAO.QueryDef
Dim MyRecordset As DAO.Recordset

'Step 2: Identify the database and query
Set MyDatabase = DBEngine.OpenDatabase _
("\\folders\Awesome.accdb")
Set MyQueryDef = MyDatabase.QueryDefs("AwesomeQuery")

'Step 3: Define the Parameters
With MyQueryDef
.Parameters("[Enter Parameter:]") = [Parameter].Value
End With

'Step 4: Open the query
Set MyRecordset = MyQueryDef.OpenRecordset

'Step 5: Clear previous contents
[DataInputRange].ClearContents

'Step 6: Copy the recordset to Excel
[DataInput].CopyFromRecordset MyRecordset

'MsgBox "Your Query has been Run"

LetsContinue:
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

On Error Resume Next

MyRecordset.Close
MyQueryDef.Close
MyDatabase.Close

Set MyRecordset = Nothing
Set MyQueryDef = Nothing
Set MyDatabase = Nothing

On Error GoTo 0
Exit Sub

Whoa:
MsgBox "Oh noes!!1" & vbCrLf & _
"Error Description :" & Err.Description & vbCrLf & _
"Error at line     :" & Erl & vbCrLf & _
"Error Number      :" & Err.Number

Resume LetsContinue  

End Sub
```

Comment: How good is your error handling set up?

Comment: I added some basic error catching, in the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a gigantic idiot.

I had a user send me a copy of the tool when it errored, to try and dig into the issue, and realized that although not all the data was populating, it was happening later in the process. All of the raw data was in fact making it into the tool. My apologies -_-